# Postgres and 1000 multiple calls

Tags: node.js, postgresql, parallel-processing

I have a DB PostgresSql Server v. 11.7 - which is used 100% for local development only.
Hardware: 16 cores CPU, 112 GB memory, 3TB m.2 SSD (It is running Ubuntu 18.04 - But I get the about the same speed at my windows 10 laptop when I run the exact same query locally on it).

The DB contains ~ 1500 DB table (of the same structure).
Every call to the DB is custom and specific - so nothing to cache here.
From NodeJS I execute a lot of simultaneously calls (via await Promise.all(all 1000 promises)) and afterwards make a lot of different calculations.

Currently my stats look like this (max connection set to the default of 100):

1 call ~ 100ms

1.000 calls ~ 15.000ms (15ms/call)

I have tried to change the different settings of PostgreSQL. For example to change the max connections to 1.000 - but nothing really seems to optimize the performance (and yes - I do remember to restart the PostgreSql service every time I make a change).

How can I make the execution of the 1.000 simultaneously calls as fast as possible? Should I consider to copy all the needed data to another in-memory database like Redis instead?

The DB table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table1 (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    tradeid int8 NOT NULL,
    matchdate timestamptz NULL,
    price float8 NOT NULL,
    "size" float8 NOT NULL,
    issell bool NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT my_table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX my_table1_matchdate_idx ON public.my_table1 USING btree (matchdate);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table1_tradeid_idx ON public.my_table1 USING btree (tradeid);
```

The simple test query - fetch 30 mins of data between two time-stamps:

```
select * from my_table1 where '2020-01-01 00:00' <= matchdate AND matchdate < '2020-01-01 00:30'

total_size_incl_toast_and_indexes   21 GB total table size -->  143 bytes/row
live_rows_in_text_representation    13 GB total table size -->  89  bytes/row
```

My NodeJS code looks like this:

```
const startTime = new Date();
let allDBcalls = [];
let totalRawTrades = 0;

(async () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        allDBcalls.push(selectQuery.getTradesBetweenDates(tickers, new Date('2020-01-01 00:00'), new Date('2020-01-01 00:30')).then(function (rawTradesPerTicker) {
            totalRawTrades += rawTradesPerTicker["data"].length;
        }));
    }
    await Promise.all(allDBcalls);
    _wl.info(`Fetched ${totalRawTrades} raw-trades in ${new Date().getTime() - startTime} ms!!`);
})();
```

I just tried to run EXPLAIN - 4 times on the query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM public.my_table1 where '2020-01-01 00:00' <= matchdate and matchdate < '2020-01-01 00:30';



Index Scan using my_table1_matchdate_idx on my_table1  (cost=0.57..179.09 rows=1852 width=41) (actual time=0.024..0.555 rows=3013 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (('2020-01-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone <= matchdate) AND (matchdate < '2020-01-01 00:30:00+04'::timestamp with time zone))
  Buffers: shared hit=41
Planning Time: 0.096 ms
Execution Time: 0.634 ms

Index Scan using my_table1_matchdate_idx on my_table1  (cost=0.57..179.09 rows=1852 width=41) (actual time=0.018..0.305 rows=3013 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (('2020-01-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone <= matchdate) AND (matchdate < '2020-01-01 00:30:00+04'::timestamp with time zone))
  Buffers: shared hit=41
Planning Time: 0.170 ms
Execution Time: 0.374 ms

Index Scan using my_table1_matchdate_idx on my_table1  (cost=0.57..179.09 rows=1852 width=41) (actual time=0.020..0.351 rows=3013 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (('2020-01-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone <= matchdate) AND (matchdate < '2020-01-01 00:30:00+04'::timestamp with time zone))
  Buffers: shared hit=41
Planning Time: 0.097 ms
Execution Time: 0.428 ms

Index Scan using my_table1_matchdate_idx on my_table1  (cost=0.57..179.09 rows=1852 width=41) (actual time=0.016..0.482 rows=3013 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (('2020-01-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone <= matchdate) AND (matchdate < '2020-01-01 00:30:00+04'::timestamp with time zone))
  Buffers: shared hit=41
Planning Time: 0.077 ms
Execution Time: 0.586 ms
```

Comment: 15ms per call doesn't seem to bad. How fast do you need that to be? But without seeing the actual queries, the table and index definitions this is impossible to answer

Comment: Also: how do you measure the time? Does it include network delay and front-end processing? What is the volume of data transferred per call?

Comment: Does NodeJS use a connexion pool ? If yes, how is it configured ? If no, there is some overhead in PostgreSQL to create 1000 connexions if this is done during the test.

Comment: First of all something seems wrong - when changing the PostgreSQL settings doesn't do anything? Second, I need it to be lightning fast/ as fast as possible ...we are running millions (if possible billions) of tests on the data. I will include the table definition + query in a few!

Comment: I simply start the timer in NideJS like: const startTime = new Date().getTime(); and when it has executed all 1000 promises and returned I do a new Date().getTime() - startTime. No network is included in the test / Both DB Server and the NodeJS app is currently running on the  same machine (either the powerfull server or on my powerfull dell xps laptop as well). Every row is 89 bytes and 3.013 rows are fetched each time in my test here = 268KB and 1000 times is then 268MB,,, and my laptop has 32GB of memory and the DB server has 112GB of memory so it should be a none issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of the query, preferably with `track_io_timing` turned on first.

Comment: "max connection set to the default of 100"  Is NodeJS using all of them?  Having 100 processes fighting over 16 CPUs is probably not productive.  They still need to do the same amount of work, but now they need to coordinate with each other on top of that.

Comment: Do you have 16 real cores, or do you have 8 real cores with some (probably useless) hyperthreading thrown in?

Comment: Yes NodeJS uses pooling --> Like this: https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling + I have also updated my post now with an EXPLAIN query :) My laptop is an 6 cores intel i9 (12 HT) + the DB server has 16 cores AMD Threadripper (32 HT).

Comment: Another thing: const client = await pool.connect(); this call right now suddenly takes 20 seconds!? Yes seconds! The EXPLAIN query in the DB still shows 0.5-2ms!? How is it possible to change so much?